# Flurry is not recording my sessions Android

Tags: android, analytics, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am using Flurry Analytics and my minsdk is 15 so I believe I dont have to do all that onStartSession, onStopSession stuff.

```
    FlurryAgent.init(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
```

I have put this in every one of my activities, is this correct? Is there anything I am missing or have done wrong?

In my log I can see things like:

```
    Flurry session ended
    FlurryAgent﹕ Flurry session started for context:......
```

But it never ends up reflecting in Flurry, I know there is a delay and I have been using it for a few days so I know that it is defintely not working

Answer (score 0):

You generally should only make a single call to FlurryAgent.init(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); in your apps main thread. Special handling is only required if your app supports Android APIs < 14.

Flurry's event logs will update in 5-7 minutes or less so add a test event after you begin the session. You should see the event in the logs very soon after the session ends.

At the end of your test session close the app with the home button. If the problem persists please send us your api key and code snippets to support@flurry.com.

Comment: Ok great, so onCreate in my first activity have my FlurryAgent.init(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); and FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true); then I dont need anything else in the other activities other than events?

Comment: Yes, as long as your app only supports Android sdks 14 and above. Be sure to include the dependencies listed here: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/ Be sure to clode the app with the home button and the events should show in the event logs in a short time(a couple of minutes) If you have anymore trouble send me an email to support@flurry.com

Comment: What did you mean by "be sure to clode the app with the home button"

Comment: I am sorry I meant "close the app with the home button"